# Open Source APS software (Advanced Planning and Scheduling systems)

Tags: open-source, scheduling, planning, algorithms

### I'm searching for a simple APS software as a **starting point** for a project (industrial field). Where to start?

Here some elements:

- It has to be **open-source** (no paid solutions). As of today I don't know the software requirements. It must be a starting point on which to start a development, according to clients needs.
- It must manage models like: operator, machine, work shift
- Its **purpose** is to organize (automatically and manually) the week/month workload by work priority, operator available time, machine availability, type of work, ...

  - OS: probably Windows environment.

I know: too few details ...

---

UPDATES

- I've only found [FET](https://www.lalescu.ro) and [UNITIME](http://www.unitime.org/) (school field)
- I've found [ProjeQtor](https://www.projeqtor.org/en/). Anyone knows / have experienced using/customizing this software?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what features do you need? What's your price margin if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: I know nothing of the topic, but SourceForge has 245 FOSS apps which you could consider. See [here](https://sourceforge.net/directory/?q=advanced+planning+and+scheduling)

Comment: Do you mean that it should be [tag:gratis] but you might not get the source code, or that it must be [tag:open-source]? Please add the appropriate tag. And which operating system do you use (or should it be cloud based)? If you don't help us, it is difficult for us to help you.

Comment: @Mawg I edited my question

Comment: And I upvoted. I hope that the changes to the question will get you a good answer. Like I said, it is not my area of knowledge, but you can also take a look on SourceForge at the link given in my previous comment. Welcome aboard - I hope that you find your answer :-)

Comment: Suggest you put the ones you've found in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [ProjeQtor](https://www.projeqtor.org/en/).

> ProjeQtOr  is an open source project management software grouping in a single tool all the features needed to organize your projects. It is simple, easy to use while covering a maximum of project management features. 
>   Its particularity, in addition to its completeness, is to be quality oriented.
>   This means that you can record all the events on your projects, and thereby simplify compliance with leading standards of quality management, whether ISO, CMMI, ITIL or other.